# How to change schema name in Crystal report 11?

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, ora-00942

The report is being designed in Crystal Reports XI.

It uses an ODBC connection to an Oracle database using the CR Oracle ODBC driver 4.1.

I need this report to be easily distributed across 14 sites that use the same ODBC DSN, but the database at each site has a different owner and/or schema name.

I followed Business Objects instructions to modify the fully qualified name for each table in a report:

1. On the 'Database' menu, click 'Set Datasource Location'. The 'Set Datasource Location' dialog box appears.
2. In the 'Current Data Source' area, expand the list of current connections in order to view each table in the report.
3. For each table in the report:

   i. Expand the 'Properties' list.

   ii. Click 'Overridden Qualified Table Name', and then press the F2 key or double-click.

   iii. Move the cursor to the end of the text and type the table name.

   iv. Press Enter.

I am getting error

> Crystal Reports
>
> Failed to retrieve data from the database.
>
> Details: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>
> [Database Vendor Code: 942 ]

I either need a fix for these errors or a better way to make these Oracle reports more portable.